# Merge [.net-generics] into [generics]?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Is [.net-generics](/questions/tagged/.net-generics) really required? Should it be merged into more general [generics](/questions/tagged/generics), with appropriate synonym added?

Comment: Don't you mean more generic generics?

Comment: @squillman: That's what exactly was in my mind ;)

Comment: @Shot9: Thanks! Could you please post an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 6):

True, in most cases I don't see the benefit of combined tags. To achieve the same result you can easily tag the question [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)[generics](/questions/tagged/generics).

However [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) does make sense, as you don't want a tag [4.0](/questions/tagged/4.0).

Comment: Or you might want to _tag_ the question instead.  ;)

Comment: @Jeff: Those words are so similar ... :)

Comment: `.net-4.0` is not a *combined* tag, it's a version tag. ;)