# Should we tag questions with [category][subcategory] or [category-subcategory]?

Tags: discussion, tags, policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should “compound” tags be allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93607/should-compound-tags-be-allowed)

Example tag: [java-io](/questions/tagged/java-io)

- It has the potential to keep a question from the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag. (For this example, [it has happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-io+-java?sort=newest&pagesize=50) at least a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336514/delay-in-copy-a-file-from-one-location-to-another-in-java) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797742/reading-single-character-from-console-in-java))
- The [same information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+io) can be accessed by using [java](/questions/tagged/java)[io](/questions/tagged/io), but only if you don't have separate sections like [java-io](/questions/tagged/java-io).
- The readers of the [io](/questions/tagged/io) tag has no reason to be restricted, and has no special meaning by itself.

Example Question: [Getting meaningful text from Java.io.Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683943/getting-meaningful-text-from-java-io-reader)

Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't we replace

- [java-io](/questions/tagged/java-io) with [java](/questions/tagged/java)[io](/questions/tagged/io)
- [javascript-alerts](/questions/tagged/javascript-alerts) with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[alert](/questions/tagged/alert)
- [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) with [html](/questions/tagged/html)[table](/questions/tagged/table)

I just want to check if there is a policy or disagreement on this before I start taking action. (my edits are no longer "peer-reviewed")

Comment: Note this from the [Android Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android): Please use the Android-specific tags such as [android-intent], not [intent].

Comment: Your best bet on this is going to be asking about these on a case-by-case basis.  Splitting up [tag:html-table] and [tag:javascript-alerts] seems to make sense, but [tag:java-io] might be a minefield as there's a class hierarchy starting with `java.io`-with-a-dot, which is a *tag synonym* for [tag:java-io]-with-a-hyphen.

Comment: @Charles case by case is extremely impractical due to the infinite theoretical uses and hundreds of practical uses of such tags...we really do need a standard way if we don't already have one.